# declare activesheet to array for printing 2 sheets of workbook

Tags: excel, printing, vba

I am trying to print the active worksheet and another worksheet  with general information (in the same workbook) at the same time. (Recto verso, which my printer does automatically, no code needed for that)

In my workbook I have multiple sheets that use the same code for printing. Now I would like to add the sheet with general information called "Huurvoorwaarden" to an array so it is printed automaticaly and at the back side of the active sheet.

I have tried multiple sollutions like dim / set activesheet.name, and codes which I have found on the web. nothing works.
I know that when I would change "activesheet" to Sheet1, that would work, but only for sheet 1.

Could you please help me?

Here is what I have got: (all my older attempts are deleted)

```
    'Print Active Sheet and sheet Huurvoorwaarden
    Worksheets(Array("activesheet.name", "Huurvoorwaarden")).PrintOut
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name of the active sheet is not the string literal `"ActiveSheet.Name"`, it is the property `ActiveSheet.Name`.

So you need to use

```
Worksheets(Array(Activesheet.Name, "Huurvoorwaarden")).PrintOut
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It does print the two pages now, but it doesn't print recto-verso anymore. With this code it does:        Worksheets(Array("Blad1", "Huurvoorwaarden")).PrintOut. But then again it does not print the active sheet. Doubble sided printing is a standard feature on my printer. Any suggestions?

Comment: There should be no difference whether the `Array` function is passed two strings both of which are string literals, or whether it is passed two strings one of which has been obtained from a variable.  In both cases it receives two `String`s.  And the `Worksheets` object doesn't know **how** the array of strings it is passed as an index was created, and the `PrintOut` method has no idea of how the `Worksheets` object has determined which worksheets are to be printed.

Comment: Thank you once again. I have tried this code once more - and now it works fine. No idea why it didn't a few days ago. I realy appreciate  your help!