# Select ActiveSheet and Specified Sheets

Tags: arrays

I want to setup a macro that will allow me to print to PDF a certain list of links along with the sheet I have selected when I initiate the macro. I had thought I could use the below for setting the selection but it isn't working.

```
Sub Macro2()

    Dim wsA As Worksheet
    Dim MyArray As Variant

    Set wsA = ActiveSheet

    MyArray = Array("Contacts", "PersonalLinks", "banklogins", "time", wsA)
    Sheets(MyArray).Select
End Sub
```

What am I missing/doing wrong with this? Thanks for any help you can offer.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the answer on the question

[declare activesheet to array for printing 2 sheets of workbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46970978/declare-activesheet-to-array-for-printing-2-sheets-of-workbook)

So the code needs to be

```
Sub Macro2()

    Dim MyArray As Variant

    MyArray = Array("Contacts", "PersonalLinks", "banklogins", "time", ActiveSheet.Name)
    Sheets(MyArray).Select
End Sub
```

Now just need to add in the print to PDF code.